# Добавление сообщений ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

При нажатии на кнопку новые сообщения не появляются ниже, а перезаписывают первое сообщение

```
<?
if(isset($_POST)){
          $data=date("d-m-y");
          $poluchatel=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$poluchatel);
          $textarea=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$textarea);                  
          $query_2="INSERT INTO dialog(author, poluchatel, mess, data)VALUES('{$_SESSION['id']}', '$poluchatel', '$mess', '$data')";
          $result_2=mysqli_query($con,$query_2) or die (mysqli_error($con));                       
}
?>


 <div class="chat-message-left pb-4">
            <div>
              <img src="images/avatar.jpg" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40" height="40">
              <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">   <?=$data?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 ml-3">
              <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1" style="font-size: 14px;"><? echo "$name";  ?></div>
             <?=$textarea?>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: откуда $name берется?

Comment: @BearVorkuta не вставил просто

Answer (score 0):

Вы получаете одну строку в запросе sql. `mysql_fetch_array` выведет только 1 ряд.

В вашем случае надо типа:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    //и тут уже обрабатываете данные из базы, типа $name = $row["name"], и так далее.
}
```